# Proper syntax for super()?

Tags: java, superclass

When I use super() to use a superclass method, what is the proper way to return?

Let's say I have a class Hourly. It contains a constructor also called Hourly that has parameters "String name" and "double rate. The UML version looks like:

+Hourly(name:String, rate:double)

However, the "name" variable is a private attribute of the Employee class, of which the class hourly is related to via inheritance. By this I mean that the UML show a clear arrow (not a diamond) going from the class Hourly and pointing to the class Employee.

How would I write the constructor Hourly???

I have a basic skeleton of:

```
public Hourly(String name, double rate){


}
```

Please help me fill it in.

On a separate note, let's say that there was a return in a method. Say I wanted to return the `double rate`.  What would be the proper syntax to return some that uses super() as I know I couldn't simply use:

```
return this.rate;
```

Comment: What constructors and accessor ("getter") methods does the `Employee` superclass expose?

Comment: getPay() and there's a printPay(date:int)

Both are not much help

Comment: If Hourly is sub class of Employee and if you want to parse the name to super class (Employee) then in your Hourly constructor call super(name);

Comment: could you give an answer with code, please?

Comment: is there a setter for name in the Employee class, or is it in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Employee` surely has a name.

```
private String name;

public Employee(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Following that, your `Hourly` must also have a name.  Since an `Hourly` is-an `Employee`, you must set the name on it as well.  That is accomplished like so.

```
public Hourly(String name, double rate) {
    super(name);
    this.rate = rate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, name is stored by the superclass; rate is not.  So you should store rate in the `Hourly` class you're defining, while passing name to the super constructor, as follows:

```
public class Hourly {

  private double rate;

  public Hourly(String name, double rate) {
    super(name);
    this.rate = rate;
  }

  public double getRate() {
    return rate;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Hourly is sub class of Employee and if you want to parse the name to super class (Employee) then in your Hourly constructor call super(name);

```
public Hourly(String name, double rate){
    super(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Hourly extends Employee`:

```
    class Hourly extends Employee {

    private int rate;

    public Hourly(String name, int rate) {
      super(name);  //assuming Employee has this constructor
      this.rate = rate;
    }

    //this make sense if name is protected and doesn't have getter in base class
    //ideally you would have this in base class itself
    public String getName() {
       return super.name; //for rate there is no sense in using super as it is not known to super class
    }
    }
```